# Javascript - Google Maps API V3 draw line on street using street name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently creating a custom map using the Javascript Google Maps V3 API.

I alreay know how to add markers, but currently I need to do something more "complex".
I need help right now to find a way to draw in the map, lines in the streets that I want.

Do you know how to do it or have some reference?

Comment: GMaps API V3 has a very nice documentation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a good starting point and refernece for you to research further, this uses google polylines to draw lines on map for this example, the user pick to points on the map and a line is contructed...Please not you will have to use a valid key for this example to work... hope this helps best of luck

```js
      // This example creates an interactive map which constructs a polyline based on
      // user clicks. Note that the polyline only appears once its path property
      // contains two LatLng coordinates.

      var poly;
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.879, lng: -87.624}  // Center the map on Chicago, USA.
        });

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3
        });
        poly.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event
        map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
      }

      // Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
      function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();

        // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
        // and it will automatically appear.
        path.push(event.latLng);

        // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          title: '#' + path.getLength(),
          map: map
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex Polylines</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```